R stats `aov` uses all available cores instead of just one
I’m analysing the impact of a covariate on a dependent variable using aov to assess how much variation can be reduced by including said covariate.
However, when I run the function, it automatically uses all available cores on my shared HPC node (~64 cores, as shown in the attached screenshot), which affects other users on the node.

Here is the function along with some data to reproduce the behavior:
explained_variance_aov <- function(pc, data, covar) {

    # Create the formula dynamically based on the PC variable
    formula <- as.formula(str_interp("${pc} ~ ${covar}"))

    # Fit the model
    model <- aov(formula, data = data %>% select(c(!!sym(pc), !!sym(covar))) %>% tidyr::drop_na())

    # Extract the sum of squares
    anova_summary <- model %>% broom::tidy()
    SSB <- anova_summary %>%
        filter(term == covar) %>%
        pull(sumsq) # Between-groups sum of squares
    SST <- anova_summary %>%
        pull(sumsq) %>%
        sum()

    R_squared <- (SSB / SST) * 100

    # Return the ICC percentage as a named result
    return(data.frame(
        PC = pc,
        explained_var = R_squared
    ) %>% remove_rownames())
}

n <- 60000  
n_pcs <- 3000  

data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n * n_pcs, mean = 0, sd = 1), nrow = n, ncol = n_pcs))
colnames(data) <- paste0("PC", 1:n_pcs)
data$covar <- factor(sample(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), n, replace = TRUE))


# Example usage of the function for multiple PCs
results <- lapply(paste0("PC", 1:3000), function(pc) {
    explained_variance_aov(pc, data, "covar")
}) %>% bind_rows()

# Print results for the first few PCs
print(head(final_results))

I tried changing different default settings, but nothing helped...
Sys.setenv(OMP_NUM_THREADS = 1)  
Sys.setenv(MKL_NUM_THREADS = 1)  
Sys.setenv(OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS = 1)  
options(mc.cores = 1)

Any idea why this is happening and how to only use a single core for the analysis? I don't want to throttle the worker node for all other users.

Some of those settings may need to be applied before the R session starts, i.e. Sys.setenv() from within an R session might not work as expected.  Check out the RphcBLASctl package, which offers
blas_set_num_threads(threads)
omp_set_num_threads(threads)


If BLAS threading cannot be controlled and persists with multithreading, consider using explicit parallel processing to ensure proper thread control. For example:
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(1)  # Single core

clusterExport(cl, list("explained_variance_aov", "data"))

results <- parLapply(cl, paste0("PC", 1:3000), function(pc) {
    explained_variance_aov(pc, data, "covar")
})

stopCluster(cl)

results <- do.call(rbind, results)

